# Drawing error bars on a position vs time chart where st. dev. is for vectors and not total position

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, error

I have the following data for a position versus time analysis.

[image]

Note that the total distance is just the sum of the mean vector distances. I want to show the error bars on a chart of total distance vs time.  The issue is that the st. dev. shown in the table is per vector segment not the total distance.  So for example at time 0.000125 the position on the chart is shown under the total distance column as 0.000407.  But the st. dev. error is for the measurement of the vector from time 0.000083 to 0.000125 and not from 0 to 0.000125.  I don't know if this makes a difference.  Do I just show the st. dev. for the vector at the point (in this case st. dev. equals 0.000018).  The issue I'm not resolving in my mind is what about the error from previous vectors?  The previous vector has an error of 0.000024. And then there is error from the vector before that. Don't I need to account for these prior errors somehow?  Would they just be added?  I guess what I'm saying is if the error for the first segment is 11% and the second segment has an error of 24%, what is the error for the two segments together over the total distance from 0 to the end of the second segment (or third, or fourth, etc.)? Doesn't the 11% error from the first segment add additional uncertainty about where the total position or distance would be by the end of the second segment?